# Syntax error token ";", { expected

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a simple app in the android adt that merely selects one of 5 choices when the screen is tapped and prints it onto the screen. I don't even know if my code will work as I am brand new to java, but so far the only error left is on the line with public static final. Until this point it is just the default code.

```
        /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    if(GestureDetector.OnGestureListener){
        String[] myStringArray = {"Option 1","Option 2","Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5"};
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        Log.d(TAG, myStringArray[n]);
        }
}}
```

Comment: You've defined a class PlaceholderFragment and then you're closing the curly brace so you're done with that class.  You can't just write code after that like you're doing so you get a syntax error. It's not a valid program.  Your class needs to implement various other life cycle calls, see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Your if statement is not in a method... that may cause problems.

Comment: I am so disappointed to see so many people jumping to Android without even knowing Java ...

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {


     // place this line here........................      
 public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        } }

    if(GestureDetector.OnGestureListener){
        String[] myStringArray = {"Option 1","Option 2","Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5"};
        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        Log.d(TAG, myStringArray[n]);
        } }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mis-placed the if()

```
if(GestureDetector.OnGestureListener){
    String[] myStringArray = {"Option 1","Option 2","Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5"};
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  n = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
    Log.d(TAG, myStringArray[n]);
    }
```

The above if() is meaningless in your code. Thats the cause of the syntax error you got.
And you need to delete the 2 excess closing curly braces(}})